# What does 'd' mean in '/etc/cron.d'?

Tags: linux

On Linux systems there are some special paths like `/etc/cron.d/`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. That are the paths where you can place your own custom configs in separate files.

My question is — what does letter `d` mean?

Comment: Off-topic. `d` for `directory`?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-directory-names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

directory :) Since there can possibly be a `/etc/cron` file as well. It is the same for `/etc/modprobe.d/`